How to securely store api credentials in a native appliaction in a cross-platform manner
I have a program that interacts with an api using the oauth2 flow. In order not to bother the user every time the program is launched to enter their login and password. I want to store the refresh token somewhere securely in a cross-platform manner. Is this the right approach?. What is the best way to do that in c++?
This topic seems to be discussed a lot but only from the perspective of websites, where they can use  cookies to store the refresh token.

Each operating system has its own secure storage with distinct APIs. On desktop operating systems you can use these APIs:

macOS keychain
Windows credential manager
Linux libsecret

And on mobile these APIs provide per application storage:

iOS keychain
Android shared preferences or DataStore

These libraries show the type of approach you can use:

C++ keychain
Keytar


I tried C++ keychain on linux, it prompts me to choose a password for a new keyring. It would be kind of weird if a user would be prompted that(at least I haven't seen an application that does this). Can I get rid of it?  If this is necessary how do all other applications store anything securely without prompting the user?

You might look into the approach from Electron safeStorage where you get an emcryption key private to your app and then store protected data , eg in user specific areas of the file system. I believe it avoids unwelcome prompts.
